# How can I properly use the for...next statement?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I'm new to vb.net and English is not my first language, Please note this :)

I've try  nested for...next loop but there's a problem which that value does not increase :(
Please help me!

```
  Dim h As Integer = 8
  Dim i As Integer = 5
  Dim time As String = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  Dim pno As String = PatNo.Text
  Dim itname() As String = 
{"<R>SPH", "<R>CYL", "<R>AX", "<R>AVE", "<L>SPH", "<L>CYL", "<L>AX", "<L>AVE"}

  Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
  For a As Integer = 8 To 18
      list.Add(ReceiveBox.Lines(a))
  Next
  Dim arrlist() As String = list.ToArray()

  For linerepeat As Integer = 1 To 3 
     If linerepeat = 3 Then
         i -= 3
     Else i = 5
     End If
     For g As Integer = 0 To 10
         For f As Integer = 0 To 7
             For number As Integer = 1 To 3
                 cmd.Connection = conn
                 Dim itvalue As String = Mid(arrlist(g), h, i)
                 Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO EYE_TEST VALUES ('" & time & "','" & pno & "','" & txt.Text & "','" & itname(f) & number & "','" & itvalue & "')"
                 cmd.CommandText = query
                 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 h += 7
              Next
              If h = 29 Then h = 8
          Next
          'If g = 3 And 5 And 9 Then Exit For
      Next
   Next
```

Comment: `If g = 3 And 5 And 9 Then Exit For` What are you trying to do here? and what variable value didn't increase? g, f or number? (I'm betting your problem is with h)  A little advice name variables with some significant names, g, f, h, is a bad idea for future .

Comment: The value of g does not increase, I just wrote down the names of the variables in a hurry... sorry :(  and i forgot to comment  this (If g = 3 And 5 And 9 Then Exit For)

Comment: Did you debug your code and check it or are you guessing by this `Mid(arrlist(g), h, i)`?

Comment: I have debugged the code. No exit from for f to for g.                   
the value of g in this → Mid(arrlist(g), h, i)  dosen't increase....

Comment: 1) If you want to skip some values in a small loop, it can be clearer to do something like `Dim gValues = {0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10}` so that you can do `For Each g in gValues`.

Comment: 2) You really should put the column names in the query: "INSERT INTO EYE_TEST (col1name, col2name, col3name, etc) VALUES ( etc.)`. Also, you should use SQL parameters to pass the data instead of putting them into the string, but get the rest of it working first.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your error I copied your code block and commented out lines of code that I cannot reproduce (for instance, your SQL command).

```
        Dim h As Integer = 8
        Dim i As Integer = 5
        '  Dim time As String = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        '  Dim pno As String = PatNo.Text
        '  Dim itname() As String =
        '{"<R>SPH", "<R>CYL", "<R>AX", "<R>AVE", "<L>SPH", "<L>CYL", "<L>AX", "<L>AVE"}

        '  Dim list As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        '  For a As Integer = 8 To 18
        '      list.Add(ReceiveBox.Lines(a))
        '  Next
        '  Dim arrlist() As String = list.ToArray()

        For linerepeat As Integer = 1 To 3
            If linerepeat = 3 Then
                i -= 3
            Else : i = 5
            End If
            For g As Integer = 0 To 10
                For f As Integer = 0 To 7
                    For number As Integer = 1 To 3
                        'cmd.Connection = conn
                        'Dim itvalue As String = Mid(arrlist(g), h, i)
                        'Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO EYE_TEST VALUES ('" & time & "','" & pno & "','" & txt.Text & "','" & itname(f) & number & "','" & itvalue & "')"
                        'cmd.CommandText = query
                        'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        
                        h += 7
                    Next
                    If h = 29 Then h = 8
                Next
                'If g = 3 And 5 And 9 Then Exit For
                 Debug.Print(" g:" & g)
            Next
        Next
```

I then added `Debug.Print(" g:" & g)` at the end of your "g" for loop to see if it was iterating. When I debug this I get the following output:

```
 g:0
 g:1
 g:2
 g:3
 g:4
 g:5
 g:6
 g:7
 g:8
 g:9
 g:10
 g:0
 g:1
 g:2
 g:3
 g:4
 g:5
 g:6
 g:7
 g:8
 g:9
 g:10
 g:0
 g:1
 g:2
 g:3
 g:4
 g:5
 g:6
 g:7
 g:8
 g:9
 g:10
```

This shows that the "g" for loop is iterating.

Try adding `Debug.Print(" g:" & g)` at the end of your "g" for loop. When you run the program the results will show in the **Output** window (if you do not see this window, click View -> Output). If you do not get the same results as me then I would expect the problem to be caused by your SQLConnection object or the query you try to execute. Maybe during one of the iterations a value does not get set properly and an error is caused which might end your for loop unexpectedly.